# dotcms osgi plugin from examples web interceptor

Tags: osgi, demo, dotcms

I'm evaluating dotcms through the docker demo, version 22.02
I'm trying the plugin samples provided by dotcms, example:
https://github.com/dotCMS/plugin-seeds/tree/master/OSGi/com.dotcms.webinterceptor

I can build the plugin and deploy it through the dotcms UI. But when I try to access the plugin (http://localhost:8080/app/helloworld?action=wrap) I got a 404 error.

I tried to replace /app by /application or remove /app in the url but same result: 404 error.

Where is the problem? The code is an example from dotcms and the demo docker is also provided by dotcms.

I'm evaluating the product and don't want to spend days to test plugin dev capabilities.

Thanks for your help

Regards,

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

The example was expecting a service reference that no longer exists and so never properly inited.   I've updated the example and removed the old reference. Please pull it down and try it again.

https://github.com/dotCMS/plugin-seeds/tree/master/OSGi/com.dotcms.webinterceptor

Comment: This is updated link. https://github.com/dotCMS/plugin-seeds/tree/master/com.dotcms.webinterceptor